# Refactoring Local Authentication Framework for Cleaner Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, refactoring

I successfully implemented Local Authentication Framework in my code by adding the method to my ViewController, but I want to refactor my code to embrace MVC pattern more effectively. I want to move the code into an NSObject and call it separately, but I'm running into two problems.

For reference, this is the code I'm implementing: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LocalAuthentication_Framework/

First problem is that the code is not firing when I test it with a UIButton touch, and the second problem is that I want to call performSegueWithIdentifier when successful but I need a UIViewController to call it. So this is what I tried at first:

```
Authenticate.h     
@interface Authenticate : NSObject
- (void)startAuthenticating;

Authenticate.m 
@implementation Authenticate
- (void)startAuthenticating{
    LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
    NSError *authError = nil;
    ...                          
    if (success) {
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Success" sender:nil];
    ...
    } ...   
  }
```

^ [self performSegue...] would throw an error here, which I understand.

```
#import "Authenticate.h"
ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic, strong) Authenticate *touchID;

ViewController.m
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    ...
    [self.touchID startAuthenticating];
  }
```

I also tried to 
`#import "ViewController.h"` into the Authenticate.h and add
`@property(nonatomic, weak) ViewController *viewController;`
and instead of the `[self performSegue...]` it became 
`[self.viewController performSegue...]` even though that seems like a retain cycle.

Currently, I have refactored my code by implementing Local Authentication framework into another UIViewController and subclassed my main ViewController under that AuthenticationViewController, but that feels like a cheat to me since that is not what I was aiming to do. Could someone please show me how to accomplish this in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why your code is not firing. But for the second problem do something like following :

In Authenticate class write the method as,

```
- (void)startAuthenticatingWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError *error))completion{
    LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
    NSError *authError = nil;

    if (success) {
        completion(YES, nil);
        //[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Success" sender:nil];

    } else {
        completion(NO, authError);
    }
}
```

And in ViewController class call the method like,

```
[self.touchID startAuthenticatingWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            [self performSegue...];
        }
    }];
```